# Form validation error - equalTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Iam using the jQuery validate library to validate a form. For some reason it is erroring when I trying to add confirm-email. The error is  Unexpected token -

The id is correct in the HTML.

```
var validation_options = {
focusInvalid: false,

rules: {
    name:           { required: true },
    houseno:        { required: true },
    streetname:     { required: true },
    postcode:       { required: true, postcodeUK: true },
    country:        { required: true },
    phone:          { required: true, validPhone: true },
    email:          { required: true, email: true, unique: true },
    confirm-email:  { required: true, equalTo: "#email" }
},


messages: {
    name:           "Please enter your name",
    houseno: {
        required:   "Please enter your house number",
    },
    streetname:     "Please enter your street name",

    postcode: {
        required:   "Please enter your postcode",
        postcodeUK: "Please enter a valid postcode"
    },

    country:        "Please enter your country",

    phone: {
        required:   "Please enter your mobile number",
        validPhone: "Please enter a valid phone number"
    },
    email: {        
        required:   "Please enter your email",
        email:      "Please enter a valid email address",
        unique:     "This email has already been used"
    },

    confirm-email: {
        required: "Please enter your email"
    }   

},
```

Comment: @Ram, since its a single value for the eamil option , you dont need a comma, its just a seperator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash is an illegal character for a variable name, it will get interpreted as a minus sign. You'll have to change confirm-email to confirm_email or something.

Comment: ... or simply put it in single- or double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is only half correct.  Yes, characters such as a dash, `-`, brackets, `[]`, or a dot, `.` will be a problem for this plugin.  However, you ***are not*** required to change `confirm-email` into `confirm_email` or something else.

You simply need to enclose the name in quotes.

```
rules: {
    'confirm-email':  {
        required: true,
        equalTo: "#email"
     }
}
```

See [the **"Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)"** section on the **"General Guidelines"** page of the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference).

**Working Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/Zaf8N/